# Getting the proper shading within a circle - a bit of litography

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, I have a diameter drawn in a circle.  Along the diameter, I draw seven equally spaced nodes.  The two nodes closest to the center, but not the center, are labeled `B` and `C`.  I want to get a certain shaded pattern - shaded gray - within the circle.

Here is the procedure. First, fill the circle with a shade of gray.  (I chose `gray!30`.)  Second, use the `fill=white` option to get a white semicircle centered at `B` that is above the diameter and a white semicircle centered at `C` that is below the diameter. Third, draw two circles, filled-in with `gray!30` of radius 1 centered at `(-2,0)` and `(2,0)`.

Here is my code.  I get an error - there is something wrong with the command that I use to `fill`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill=gray!30] (O) circle (3);
\draw[fill] (-3,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-1,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (1,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);

\node[anchor=east] (A) at (-3,0) {$A$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (-1,0) {$B$};
\node[anchor=north east] at  (1,0) {$C$};
\node [anchor=west] at (3,0) {$D$};

\draw[fill=white] (-1,0) circle (2);
\draw[fill=white] (1,0) circle (2);
\draw[fill=gray!30] (-2,0) circ (1);
\draw[fill=gray!30] (2,0) circ (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are tired! get some rest and replace those `circ` with `circle`.

Comment: [Is this what you want?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xLwim.png)

Comment: @Harish Kumar  That mistake is utterly ridiculous!  Not tired. (It is just after noon in New York.)  I wasn't wearing my glasses.

Comment: @Harish Kumar  The pattern is nearly what I want.  I will use `path` to draw the two small circles of radius 1 - I just want the shading inside these smaller circles.

Comment: @Harish Kumar  Did you notice how I spelled `circle` correctly in the last comment?

Comment: What kind of shading? inner color and outer color?

Comment: @Harish Kumar   Inner.

Comment: @Harish Kumar   Please post the code.  I don't have an efficient code of filling-in semicircles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill=gray!30] (O) circle (3);
\draw[fill] (-3,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-1,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (1,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);

\node[anchor=east] (A) at (-3,0) {$A$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (-1,0) {$B$};
\node[anchor=north east] at  (1,0) {$C$};
\node [anchor=west] at (3,0) {$D$};

\path[fill=white] (-3,0) arc (180:0:2) -- (-3,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill=white] (3,0) arc (360:180:2) -- (3,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!30] (-2,0) circle (1);
\path[fill=gray!30] (2,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the gray region to be uniform.

Comment: All the shaded region.  I guess I don't need `inner shading` and `outer shading`.

Comment: Also `\draw[fill]` can be `\filldraw`

Comment: Yes.  I am not familiar with `\path[fill=white] (-3,0) arc (180:0:2) -- (-3,0) -- cycle;`.  Please explain `(180:0:2)`.

Comment: @Adelyn `(-3,0) arc (180:0:2) ` means, start from `(-3,0)`, draw an arc with starting angle 180 with a radius 2 units and end with an angle 0. Both 180 and 0 are measured from origin. You can also use  `(-3,0) arc [start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=2] ` See section 14.7 on page 153 of pgfmanual.

Comment: What would be the code for drawing the semicircle centered at (-3,1) instead of at (-3,0)?  In this case, the center of the big circle would be at (0,1) instead of at the origin.

Comment: `\draw[fill=white] (-3,1) arc (180:0:2) -- (-3,1) -- cycle;`.